# ValueError while installing and running Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

To learn about Deep Learning and Neural Networks, I am trying to install Tensorflow on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5559, 4GB RAM, Windows 10), using `conda 4.9.1` (which initially contains `Python 3.8.3`). For this, I used the following command:

`conda create -n tf tensorflow`

This ran successfully and it installed `Python 3.7.9`, `tensorflow 2.1.0` and a lot of other modules. Now I want to test whether it works or not, so in Python terminal, imported some modules. Import was successful for `math` and `numpy`. But when I import tensorflow, the process fails with the following:

```
>>> import tensorflow      

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                            
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                             
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in 
<module>                 from tensorflow_core import *                                                                                         
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in    
<module>             from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util                                                       
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load                                                       
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 959, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                              
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in 
__getattr__               module = self._load()                                                                                                 
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load                     
module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)                                                                      
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module                           
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                           
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 
49, in <module>      from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow                                                                       
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>                                                                                                                     
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *                                                            
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>                                                                                                            
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()                                                                    
File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 15, in swig_import_helper                                                                                                  
import imp                                                                                                          
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

This error occurs even if I run a program importing Tensorflow.

I checked most other tutorials and it seemed that nobody faced this error. I also tried using using lower versions of Python and Tensorflow but the same error occurs.

Can anyone find what is happening, and what should I do?

Comment: I think I've come across this issue once (with tensorflow v1 though). I do not remember the specifics, but I do remember I had to install tensorflow from source instead. What OS are you using ?

Comment: @JosephBudin I am using Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you installed `tensorflow` with conda, the conda build has some issues, try running the pip call in your conda env

`conda remove tensorflow`

then run

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: I tried with pip and pip3 and still the same problem occurred.

Comment: recreate your env and DONT use pip3, just pip to install

Comment: Tried earlier with pip, no difference.

Comment: Though my problem hasn't been still solved, but I marking it as answer due to more comments and because of bounty.

Answer (score 2):

I found that it is sometime very hard to install and import tensorflow with python version that is not 3.6.X, I recommended using python 3.6.X, it's much easier

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to downgrade the TensorFlow to 2.00. First, remove  TensorFlow from Anaconda using `conda remove tensorflow`

and then downgrade it.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

Comment: Doesn't work, initially gives error on numpy version and after correcting that the same error returns again.

Comment: @DebanjanDey Are you using Tensorflow in a virtual Environment ??

Comment: yes, created new virtual environment and then installed